# How move a jquery script like "ddaccordion.init" in an external js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, external, init, document-ready

Hi
im trying to put all my js in external js file, for the header for my site be more light.

So in my header i have this script, wich work well :

```
    ddaccordion.init({

            headerclass: "p7ABtrig", //Shared CSS class name of headers group

            contentclass: "p7ABcontent", //Shared CSS class name of contents group

            revealtype: "click", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click" or "mouseover

            mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover

            collapseprev: false, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false

            defaultexpanded: [<?= $set_expand_index?>], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content

            onemustopen: false, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)

            animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?

            persiststate: false, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?

            toggleclass: ["", "selected"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]

            togglehtml: ["", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)

            animatespeed: "normal", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"

            oninit:function(headers, expandedindices){ //custom code to run when headers have initalized

                //do nothing

            },
            onopenclose:function(header, index, state, isuseractivated){ //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed

                //do nothing
            }
      })
```

But when i try to move this script inside this external js like inside :

```
<script src="scripts/external-script.js"></script>
```

it doesnt launch anymore.
I cannot find a way to launch it from an external js file ?

This must be really newbie question :) but im really new to jquery.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think anybody's going to be able to guess what your real problem is here. Perhaps it would help if you posted more code and described exactly what it is you *want* to happen, and what exactly happens that is wrong.

Comment: oo u right sure i will post more

Comment: Bit of an obvious one, but are you importing the script after you import / run the script that creates the global variable `ddaccordion`? And are you sure `ddaccordion` is global? I haven't used it.

Comment: thanks to look at my problem. I import the script before the script that creates the global variable ddaccordion. im not sure if ddaccordion is global. ddaccordion come from there : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordion.htm hope it could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EMMERICH. I find why it wasn't working its coz my external script was loading before my global ddaccordion script, i switch it i put the ddaccordion first and after i load the external js with ddaccordion init inside it now all is ok. Really thanks :) you great.